# Clarifying the proof of limit of Thomae's function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Given the Thomae's function
$$
f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    1/q & if  x=p/q \in Q  \text{ and in lowest terms} \\
    0 & if    x \notin Q  \\
  \end{cases}
$$
 and the interval $I = [0, 1]$, show that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = 0$ for all $a \in I$.

**Proof:** Let's say we are given an $\epsilon > 0$. Pick $q$ such that $1 / q > \epsilon$. There are finite number of rationals $p / q$ satisfying this. For example, if $\epsilon = 1 / 100$, then only rationals $ 1 / 99... 98 / 99, 1 / 98...97/98,...,1/2, 1/1$ will be bigger than $\epsilon$.Pick closest such rational to $a$ and chose $\delta$ to be this distance. Now, any rational $x = p/q$ in $\delta-$neighbourhood of $a$ has $1 / q < \epsilon$.$\mid f(x) - 0 \mid = 1 / q < \epsilon$. Any irrational point in this $\delta-$neighbourhood has $\mid f(x) - 0 \mid = 0 < \epsilon$. So if $\mid x - a \mid < \delta$ then $\mid f(x) - 0 \mid < \epsilon$.

What I am not sure of is the part that says;

"Pick $q$ such that $1 / q > \epsilon$. There are finite number of rationals $p / q$ satisfying this. For example, if $\epsilon = 1 / 100$, then only rationals $ 1 / 99... 98 / 99, 1 / 98...97/98,...,1/2, 1/1$ will be bigger than $\epsilon$." I think my reasoning is correct but my argument seems not rigorous enough. Can anyone show me a rigorous proof that:

"For any $\epsilon > 0$, pick $q$ such that $1 / q > \epsilon$. There are only finitely many rationals whose denominator, in its lowest terms, is less than $q$."

**Note:** I know there are couple of similar questions but they all follow a different strategy for the proof. I want to fill the gaps in my proof because I've spent so much time on this one.

Comment: There are infinitely many rationals between $1/99$ and $2/99$. So... By the way, why do you need *finitely many* rationals?

Comment: So that I can be sure that If I pcik $\delta$ to be the smallest distance to such rationals, no such rational would be in the $\delta$-neighbourhood of $a$. But I am more confused now.

Comment: I think the requirement that they should be in the lowest term gave me the idea that they are finite.

Comment: The correct statement should be *there are only finitely many rationals whose denominator, in its lowest terms, less than $q$*. Probably that's what you meant, when you wrote those numbers. I got confused with your statement.

Comment: [This](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/a-function-continuous-at-all-irrationals-and-discontinuous-at-all-rationals/) may help you.